# when build a websocket based on Action Cable , "was interrupted while the page was loading" ,the error occur in Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, heroku

I build the web socket using rails action cable . It work well when deployed in localhost - my dev env . But when I publish my project to Heroku. Some strange things occur. The woesocket also work well in chrome and safari. But in firefox ,I got this error info in console.

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://someapp.herokuapp.com/cable. 
>   The connection to wss://someapp.herokuapp.com/cable was interrupted while the page was loading.

I read [the solutions by Todd Wolfso](https://bl.ocks.org/twolfson/c31234a82e699c8fbc0b)

That is my security.tls.version.max configuration in firefox.
[security.tls.version.max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9wc8.png)

I don't how to fix it . 
In local ,I use http ,while heroku using https!